# What is the difference between emit() and send() in flask socketio?

Tags: sockets, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I want to start using flask socketIO for live chats and games on my web app.
I am not sure what the difference is between send() and emit().

Comment: `socket.send` creates an event called "message" to send data, while `socket.emit` can create events with custom names